# Is there any function in netezza or in SQL for returning the value as row according to value indicies?

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a requirement,where the one of column values tell how many line of records should present in target i.e (that has to be change to rows depends upon the value in column). I'm looking for SQL query on this requirement. Below is one sample

Ex : Input in table

```
Col1|Col2|Col3
1|5|1,2-4,6,7-9
```

Expected output in table

```
Col|Col2|Col3
1|5|1
1|5|2
1|5|3
1|5|4
1|5|6
1|5|7
1|5|8
1|5|9
```

Comment: Do you know or can you find the maximum value that can occur in the third column?

Comment: No, we can't predict the maximum value on 3rd column.

Comment: I was thinking, if you knew the maximum, or could get it from a subquery, you could generate a sequence (in postgres this would be the `generate_series()` function) and then `JOIN` the table with the sequence and a fancy `WHERE` clause.  Instead, maybe you just need to create a function that interpret's `Col3`'s value and produces a multi-row series from it.  Good luck.